# This property cannot be set after writing has started... when did I start writing?

Tags: c#, post, oauth, httpwebrequest, dotnetopenauth

I'm making an OAuth 1.0a request to an online trading REST API.  As far as I can tell, the following code is the way to make the request, but I get a "This property cannot be set after writing has started" message on the `request.ContentLength = postData.Length;` line... I don't understand why.  If this is not the way to add POST data to an OAuth authenticated web request before it goes out, what is?

```
var request = consumer.PrepareAuthorizedRequest(new DotNetOpenAuth.Messaging.MessageReceivingEndpoint(new Uri(this.EndPointAddress, relativeUri), method), this.AccessToken);
request.Method = (method == DotNetOpenAuth.Messaging.HttpDeliveryMethods.PostRequest) ? "POST" : "GET";
if (postValues != null && postValues.Count > 0)
{
    //There is POST data associated with this request, include it
    var postData = KVPCollectionToString(postValues);
    request.ServicePoint.Expect100Continue = false;
    request.ContentLength = postData.Length;
    Logger.Trace(t => t("POST Data: {0}", postData));
    using (var stream = request.GetRequestStream())
    {
        var pBytes = System.Text.Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(postData);
        stream.Write(pBytes, 0, pBytes.Length);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Short Answer: 
If you want to pass additional information in the OAuth request, you should use one of the other overloads to [`PrepareAuthorizedRequest`](http://docs.dotnetopenauth.net/v3.4/html/O_T_DotNetOpenAuth_OAuth_ConsumerBase_PrepareAuthorizedRequest.htm). You can supply a list of POST parameters to the method that are added to the request for you.

Longer answer:

The `PrepareAuthorizedRequest` method will write to the request before you even get the `HttpWebRequest` back. This means you cannot change the content length after that happens.

To see this for yourself, you can dig into the DotNotOpenAuth source code. If you look at the [`Channel`](https://www.google.com/search?q=Channel.cs%20dotnetopenauth&rlz=1C1CHFX_enUS462US462&oq=Channel.cs%20dotnetopenauth&aqs=chrome.0.57j62.5010&ie=UTF-8) class, given the parameters to your `PrepareAuthorizedRequest` call you will eventually end up in `Channel.InitializeRequestAsPost`. You'll notice two things here:

- You don't have to set the method to POST, DotNetOpenAuth does this for you.
- To supply parameters in the request, you should be passing them into `PrepareAuthorizedRequest` using one of the other overloads which take dictionaries of name/value pairs.

Comment: This is good information to know!  Modifying my code to send the `IDictionary<string, string>` of my POST values successfully created the request.  Of course it failed for some generic `signature_method_rejected` issue, but that's another problem.  Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

It look like you are trying to write to the request stream instead of the response string, you can't modify the request only the response.

Comment: Well it has to be possible *somehow* to write to the request stream if you have request data to send.  But I'm not even getting to that point; it's blowing up on the `request.ContentLength = postData.Length;` line.

Comment: I think you're misunderstanding here (or I am). Request and Response-streams are both part of the same socket, they're just split out in InputStream and OutputStream so to speak. So you read from the Request-stream, and write to the Response-stream.

Comment: As I am making the request, would I not be writing to the request, and  reading from the response?  I *think* you are thinking of this as an ASP.NET inbound request, but this is an outbound request to an external API.  Please forgive if I am mistaken.